# Magento 2 - Check if category exists or not

Tags: magento2, category, collection

I need to check if category exist or not by category name.

I have try this with category name **test** but it does not work at the same time it does not throw any error

```
$category = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');

$cate = $category->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name','test')->getFirstItem();

if (!isset($cate)) {
    echo "not exist";
} else {
    echo "already exist";
}
```

how to deal with check if category exist or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$cate->getId()` it give false value when category does not exit

```
if (!$cate->getId()) {
    echo "not exist";
} else {
    echo "already exist";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

please make change in if condition as below:

```
if ($cate->getSize() > 0) {
    echo "already exist";
} else {
    echo "not exist";
}
```

above code should give you the desired result..

And I would recommend you use **Constructor Injection** to get the collection rather than creating it into object manager...

hope this will work...