# How to add category translation programmatically?

Tags: category, store-view, translate, magento2.3

How to add categories programmatically was described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114560/create-category-programaticaly-if-not-exist-magento-2).

Now, I have two store views (English and German) under one store.

When having added a category in englisch how can I then add the data for the German store view, that is, the translation for the category name, urlkey etc.?

In the frontend user interface this is easy. You just need to usethe store view switcher. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
$storeId = 2; // German Store ID
$categoryId = 2; // Category ID
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); // Load Category
$category->setStoreId($storeId) // set Store View for which you will make changes.
->setCategoryName('German Category Name') // set category name for selected store view
->setUrlKey('url-key-in-deutsch'); // same for url key

$category->save(); // Save and done!
```

That's all.